# For L'Hopital's Rule, do you take the derivative of the numerator and denominator independently, or use the quotient rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> When using L'Hopital's Rule, do you take the derivative of the numerator and denominator independently, or use the quotient rule?

For example: Given the problem $\lim_{x\to\ 0}{\sqrt x\ln x}$ do I put the derivative of $\ln(x)$ over the derivative of $1/\sqrt x$ or do I take the derivative of the entire thing?

Comment: You decide what $f$ and $g$ are in $\frac{f}{g}$, then you check if they satsify the hypothesis, then you evaluate the limit of $\frac{f'}{g'}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f$ and $g$ be two differentiable functions. In general,
$$
\frac{f'}{g'} \neq \left(\frac{f}{g} \right)'
$$
According to L'Hopital's rule, you take the derivative independently.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the hypotheses of L'Hospital's Rule are satisfied, to apply the theorem you take the limit of the quotient of the derivatives (as has already been pointed out).

Now, regarding the specific problem you cite:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x} \ln x$$ gives us the indeterminate form $0 \cdot \infty$.

So, we rewrite the problem and evaluate as follows: $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln x}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} = \frac{-\infty}{\infty}$, which is one of the indeterminant forms to which L'H Rule applies.

Hence, taking the limit as $x \to 0$ of the derivative of the numerator over the derivative of the denominator, we get

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{x}}} = \lim_{x \to 0} -2\sqrt{x} = 0.$$